# Como fazer com que apenas o usuário que salvou a String possa ver Flutter/Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Esse é um código que salva uma `String` de qr code que não se repete no banco, mas desse jeito todos podem acessar esses dados. Já peguei o Id do usuário mas ainda não consegui filtrar para apenas ele ver a lista.

```
void SalvarMensagem() async {

  String uid = UserModel.of(context).firebaseUser.uid;

  this._status = _status;
  _numeroSerie = _status.substring(48, 80);

  final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
      .collection("lockers")
      .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
      .limit(1)
      .getDocuments());

  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
  if (documents.length == 1) {
   // duplicado(context);
  } else {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection("lockers")
        .document()
        .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie, "userId": uid});
  }
}
```

no banco firebase:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No seu collection `lockers` crie um campo `userID` e salve nele o código do document do teu usuário logado. Depois quando for listar, filtre apenas os registros que possuírem o `userID` igual ao usuário logado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode armazenar na seu collection `lockers` o código do usuário que inseriu o QRCode e depois ao filtrar seus `lokers` você traz apenas os que possuem o respectivo código.

Ao se conectar ao firebase você pode se autenticar por email/senha, da seguinte forma

```
class Conection {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    user.email;
    return user?.uid;
  }
}
```

O método `signInWithEmailAndPassword` irá retornar o código do document criado no seu Firebase. Guarde este código para identificar qual o usuário logado.

Ao gravar seu novo QRCode, faça da seguinte forma

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection("lockers")
    .document()
    .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie, "userid": codigoSalvoAposConexao}); // se não existe grava no banco
```

Então quando você for filtrar os QRCodes traga apenas os que possuirem o `userid` igual ao do seu usuário logado atualmente.

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
  .collection("lockers")
  .where("userid", isEqualTo: "$codigoSalvoAposConexao").where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
  .limit(1)
  .getDocuments()); // verifica no banco se existe
```

*Obs.: Não me recordo se essa é a forma correta de efetuar um filtro composto de dois campos no firebase.*

Se quiser saber um pouco mais sobre como fazer login da forma que mencionei, da uma olhada [aqui](https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/simple-firebase-login-flow-in-flutter-now-firebase-23nk) que está bem explicado. (Está em inglês mas da para entender facilmente)

**Editado**

Para realizar o filtro com `limit` que você deseja, acredito ser necessário utilizar o `orderBy` antes.
Como estou sem Flutter no meu computador agora, não posso ser preciso no exemplo, mas tente algo assim:

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
  .collection("lockers")
  .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
  .where("userid", isEqualTo: "$codigoSalvoAposConexao")
  .orderBy("userid")
  .limit(1)
  .getDocuments()); // verifica no banco se existe
```

*Obs.: Acredito que o campo utilizado no `orderBy` deva ser o mesmo do `where` que o antecede.*

Comment: editei a minha foto da pergunta, consegui pegar o código do usuário, mas estou pensando um jeito de filtrar ele

Comment: @JacksonFelipeMagnabosco a forma a qual te mostrei em minha resposta, de utilizar um `where` composto não funcionou?

Comment: ele funciona mas o limit não esta dando certo, ele grama os mesmos valores no banco, estou pesquisando alguma forma que o limit(1) funcione

Comment: @JacksonFelipeMagnabosco adicionei mais um exemplo na minha resposta, verifique ela novamente e veja se resolve teu problema.

Comment: nada, só continua funcionando na consulta simples, ou ela não grava ou grava mais de uma vez a mesma string

Comment: @JacksonFelipeMagnabosco se atente ao CaseSensitive no nome dos campos. Faça um teste, verifique se ao utilizar o filtro composto SEM o `orderBy("userid").limit(1)` é retornado os documentos corretos.